Is "more than one" always treated as grammatically singular across languages with singular/plural?
In English, we say "more than one book is on the table," where "more than one" is treated as singular despite referring to a quantity greater than one. This pattern is also observed in other languages like Spanish ("más de un libro está en la mesa") and French ("plus d'un livre est sur la table"). My question is:

Are there any natural languages with a grammatical distinction between singular and plural that treat phrases like "more than one" as grammatically plural?

If so, could you provide examples and explanations of how these languages handle such constructions?Additionally, if there are no natural languages that follow this pattern, are there any constructed languages or hypothetical examples that do?

I don’t know if there are any languages that would use a different number with more than one than they would with one, but assuming the existence of a premodifying phrase like more than, it does make most sense to use the number associated with one. The fact that the end result is a multiple of entities doesn’t change the fact that syntactically it’s more than [one book], not [more than one] book_. I would also guess that pretty much all languages would use the number associated with two, not one, in half of the two books.

The logic would be fundamentally different, of course, if phrases like more/less/fewer than X are expressed in other ways, for example with an augmentative/diminutive or paucal/greater-plural suffix on the numeral itself. It wouldn’t be entirely unexpected for numerals with such suffixes to take a different number than the base number, since in that case it really is [more/less/fewer than X] book(s).

@JanusBahsJacquet it's not only about plural marking on book though, it's also about agreement targets. E.g., more than one book are on the table in Fake English. At least with pronominal targets the plural is required in English: I have bought more than one book and read them within a week. I can't think of languages off the top of my head where plural marking is required in predicative position, but one might expect some variation.

@Keelan I would definitely expect more variation there, yes. Even within English there is variation – Ngrams show that “there are more than one X” is well-attested (though less common than its singular-verb counterpart), and even the occasional “more than one X are” (though these have a very high rate of false positives and are harder to quantify). Googling the six possible Icelandic equivalents (m./f./n. of ‘one’ + sg./pl. of verb) yields very low numbers (no more than a handful of any permutation), but only the masculine has a single hit with a singular verb – the others none at all, →

→ which would indicate that Icelandic would tend to prefer the plural verb over the singular in existential constructions. Plural verb (and predicative adjectives) is apparently prescribed for non-existential/non-cleft constructions, according to Árnastofnun (»Rétt er að segja fleiri en einn maður voru handteknir en ekki „fleiri en einn maður var handtekinn“«).
